# how to pass backslash in html form

Tags: html, web-services, forms

I know very little html, I have a backend application that does a mongodb lookup. I am building a simple html screen with forms to accept value to a web service which will run the mongo query and reply on the screen.

When I pass a filename path field in my form like this

```
\\test.server.com\filetest\test
```

in my web service app, I see the value coming in as

```
%5c%5Ctest.server.com%5cfiletest%5ctest
```

how can I get the value without this translation.

Matter fact I was hoping it would come in like this

```
\\\\test.server.com\\filetest\\test
```

as that is how things got stored in mongo.

Comment: Unfortunately we also need your code. How you _pass_ a value from a client HTML page to your server side code is one thing (it may be a POST submitted form encoded as form data, it may be a POST AJAX call encoded, for example, in JSON or as URL parameters then URL encoded) or a combination of them. The second thing is how to escape things for you Mongo driver but that's a completely different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a backslash directly as it is. That's because URLs can only be **ASCII** encoded. What this means is, that when you need to pass some special characters like `Ü`, as well as characters that need to be escaped in URLs (as spaces, backslashes, etc.) you need a way to represent them with **ASCII** symbols.

In your case the URL is getting encoded and backslashes are converted to `%5c`. To have them revert to '\' you need to either:

1. Decode them back in your server-side code. This is your best bet. This is done in different ways, depending on the technology your backend uses. In PHP, for example, you can use `urldecode` function - [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).
2. Decode characters before querying in mongodb itself. This you will need to work on, because I'm not aware of a functionality that does this for you out of the box.

More info on URL encoding can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Hope this helps!