# BackSlash Converted to %5C with HTTPCLient C#

Tags: c#, httpclient

I don't understand how the conversion of my API request is managed:

Here is the source code:

```
{
    private UC_html uc;

    private string request;

    HttpClient client;

    private string authentication;

    public SuezHttp(ref UC_html uc)
    {
        this.request = "http://192.168.78.42/ProcessData/AtProcessDataREST.dll/SQL?%3CSQL%20c=%22DRIVER={AspenTech%20SQLplus};HOST=localhost;UID=WEB3_NG\\centaure;PWD=XXXXXX;Port=10014;CHARINT=N;CHARFLOAT=N;CHARTIME=N;CONVERTERRORS=N%22%20m=%2210%22%20s=%221%22%3E%3C![CDATA[select%20tempsmoyen%20from%20cie_pontbascule]]%3E%3C/SQL%3E";
        this.client = new HttpClient();
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        this.client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.request);
        this.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        this.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        this.client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        MessageBox.Show(this.client.BaseAddress.ToString(), "BASE ADR");
    }


    public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        string returnJson;
        //returnJson = "{\"data\":[{\"r\":\"D\",\"cols\":[{\"i\":0,\"n\":\"tempsmoyen\"}],\"rows\":[{\"fld\":[{\"i\":0,\"v\":\"11 minutes\"}]}]}]}";
        string result = "10 minutes";                        
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(this.request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            MessageBox.Show(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString(),"REQUEST URI");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                returnJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(returnJson, "VALUE RETURN");

                returnJson = returnJson.Replace("&#233;", "\u00e9");
                returnJson = returnJson.Replace("&#224;", "\u00e0");

                dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(returnJson);
                foreach (dynamic data in stuff.data)
                {
                    if (data.rows != null)
                    {
                        foreach (dynamic row in data.rows)
                        {
                            foreach (dynamic value in row.fld)
                            {
                                result = value.v;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                UC_html.infos.Add(new Info(DateTime.Now, "APIINFO6", result));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            UC_html.infos.Add(new Info(DateTime.Now, "APIERRO7", e.Message));
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

The issue is :
I send the request with a double \ so that C# understands it.
But the request converts this deouble \ to '%5C' so the server sends me an error telling me that it wants a UID=WEB_NG3\centaure and not UID=WEB3_NG3%5Ccentaure.

Here is the request I send:

[Request SEND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8uVr.png)

But i think HTTPClient convert the request.

Is it possible to param HTTPClient for disable this conversion.

I'm a beginner on C# sorry if is obvious.

Do you think the error come from server side ?

**EDIT**

[POSTMAN EXECUTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq0qK.png)

When i test with postman the request is executed correctly.

I don't know how postman can execute the request.

When i test with POWERSHELL i have the same issue like C#.

Comment: That's a valid URL encoding of \, your server is wrong here, it should be the one decoding the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass backslash in html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340165/how-to-pass-backslash-in-html-form) Perfectly normal, it's supposed to be encoded that way. You need to fix the server.

Comment: Side notes: `response` needs to be in a `using` to dispose it. You can't read the content twice, just store it in a variable. Consider using a proper object model to parse the JSON, rather than `dynamic`. Don't hard-code the TLS version, allow the OS to choose the best one. If you *really* needed to set it, don't set it via `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, instead use `SslProtocols` property on the `HttpClientHandler` which you can pass to the constructor of `HttpClient`. Setting the `BaseAddress` makes little sense here as you are anyway giving the full absolute path.

Comment: thank for yours answers, my problem is i don't have the hand on the server side :/

Comment: I notice there are other items in the string which are %-encoded. What happens if you %-encode the backslashes?

Comment: @AndrewMorton if i change \ by %5C in my postman request i have this response :


[
    {
        "AtPD_ErrorCode": -2147467259,
        "AtPD_ErrorString": "Failed to open connection. Data Source( CIE-NIV3 ) Connection String( DRIVER={AspenTech SQLplus};HOST=localhost;UID=WEB3_NG%5CCentaure;PWD=centaure;Port=10014;CHARINT=N;CHARFLOAT=N;CHARTIME=N;CONVERTERRORS=N )",
        "AtPD_ADO_ErrorCode": -2147467259,
        "AtPD_ADO_ErrorString": "UID must have the format: domain\\user"
    }
]

Comment: @NaelDurand I was thinking more of changing the C# code...

Comment: @AndrewMorton if i change it in the c# code the response is the same